# Background carousel to include DIVs in slide images

Tags: javascript, html

I have this Javascript background wrapper that i want to add on its images some "description" div in the middle.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var slideInterval=20000;
var slideTransition=3500;
var slideArray=["index_files/background1.jpg","index_files/background2.jpg","index_files/background3.jpg"];
jQuery.fx.interval=33;
// -->
</script>
```

As it's seen, this plugin allows me only to slide images and not DIVs.
And i want to include the description below (3 descriptions for 3 images)

```
<div style="opacity: 1 ! important;" class="description">
                    <h2>An everyday...</h2>
                    <p>Sharing rides in underground Paris...<a href="http://www.es-processing.com/mobility.htm" class="more" target="_blank" title="More">More &gt;&gt;</a></p>
                </div>
```

What is the best way to think about when i want to associate each of the 3 description Div to the above plugin `"background1...3"` so the plugin will automatically display them together. Appreciate your comments.

Comment: Your question is too broad. What have you tried? Why are you not switching to one of the countless jQuery sliders that does HTML?

Comment: @isherwood i have many, but this is the only one i have that cache the images so i have a faster download for other pages. Unless there's a way to let the other plugins cache, it will be interesting.

Comment: Perhaps add a `title` or `alt` attribute to your `img` and/or `div` tag with your desired description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really easy to do with AngularJS and BootStrap...
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
Scroll down to the Carousel Example and just modify it a little for your needs.
The example given on this page should do it though.